# Is it possible to get a Free Magic Shield?

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda

I've been playing Zelda, and I've had my Magic Shield eaten by a Like-Like in Level 6, *twice.*

It's making me think, *what if there is a way to get the Magic Shield without paying 90 or 160 rupees to some random caveman?*  Is it possible?
Game Genie codes don't count; I'm doing Zelda Classic, not actual hardware or an emulator.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Wiki](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Magical_Shield):

> The Magical Shield can be purchased from many of the shops found across Hyrule for varying amounts of Rupees; either 160, 130, or 90 Rupees depending on the shop.

It does not say that it is attainable for free anywhere, and I haven't found anything else saying you can.

Comment: I think this is accurate... in all my years of playing this game, I never remember ever finding a free shield. Finding the 90 rupee one is special and something you don't forget, since it is such a bargain. You learn to either completely avoid like likes or find ways to beat them from as far as possible (boomerang, magic rod, arrows, etc).

Answer (score 0):

90 rupees is the BEST deal you can get on a new shield. In the Super NES game A link to the past, you could get a new shield and upgrade it to level 2 for free. But original LoZ 90 rupees is the cheapest you can find.